# Sometimes the Alt+Tab window switcher gets weird and needs two keypresses to switch windows (the first Alt+Tab only highlights the current window)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

This been happening to me once every few days or so, for the last several months. It's rather bizarre.

Sometimes the Alt+Tab window switcher gets weird and it no longer switches windows on the first Alt+Tab. It just highlights the current window, and I need to press Alt+Tab+Tab instead to actually switch the window.

It always returns itself to normal behaviour after 5~30 minutes.

My current setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Switch Windows > Alt + Tab
- Not sure if relevant, but I usually have a Notepadqq window open.

Why is this happening, and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Whenever Ubuntu gets into that weird state, Alt + Shift + Tab seems to get it back into normal behaviour right away.

Comment: @ahijny I'm seeing this suddenly after upgrade to 20.04, and the workaround doesn't work. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @Dan this was a computer I only used for a few months at an internship that I don't have access to anymore, so unfortunately I can't offer much help >_<;; best bet imo is to search the gnome bug tracker to see if anyone has had the same issue